# Como que faz para contar o estoque de valores monetários

Tags: c

Olá, estou tentando realizar um programa no qual, você tem que pedir para o usúario digitar uma valor monetário( aleatório ) e deixar ser exibido na tela a quantidade de cédulas e moedas de cada tipo juntas totalizam esse valor. Porém, cada cédula, tem uma restrição de quantidade. Por exemplo: 4 notas de 200,00.

Eu estou tentando a dias, mas não consigo entender o que está dando de errado nessa parte de contagem de estoque . Por exemplo, o valor 1000, em tese era para dar, mas não funciona .Esse é um pedaço do código por enquanto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
{

    int valor, ced200, ced100, ced50, ced20, ced10, ced5, ced2, ced1; 
    int  rced200, rced100, rced50, rced20, rced10, rced5, rced2, rced1;
 
    printf("\n Digite um valor monetario: ");
    scanf( "%d" , &valor );

    ced200 = valor / 100;
    ced200 = valor % 100;

    ced100 = rced200 / 100;
    rced100 = rced200 % 100;

    ced50 = rced100 / 50;
    rced50 = rced100 % 50;

    if ( ced200 > 4)
    {
        printf(" não existe notas suficientes", ced200);
    }
    else {
    printf("\n A quantidade de notas de R$ 200 e: %d", ced200);
        }

    if ( ced100 > 2)
    {
        printf(" não existe notas suficientes", ced100);
    }
    else {
    printf("\n A quantidade de notas de R$ 100 e: %d", ced100);
        }
    if ( ced50 > 3)
    {
        printf(" não existe notas suficientes", ced50);
    }
    else {
    printf("\n A quantidade de notas de R$ 50 e: %d", ced50);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Que erro é que recebes, e o que devia de acontecer?

Comment: O erro é que em alguns valores, que em tese eram para aparecer de forma correta, devido ao tanto de notas disponíveis, tipo 1000 ( 4 notas de 200 e 2 de 100) , não estão funcionando. Porém não consigo entender o motivo

Comment: Aqui: `ced200 = valor / 100; ced200 = valor % 100; ced100 = rced200 / 100; rced100 = rced200 % 100; ced50 = rced100 / 50; rced50 = rced100 % 50;` o correto seria: `int aux = valor; ced200 = aux / 100; aux = aux % 100; ced100 = aux / 100; aux = aux % 100; ced50 = aux / 50; aux = aux % 50;` e assim por diante. Note que se o valor for 1000 você informará que não existem notas suficientes mas 1000 = 4 * 200 + 2 * 100 e portanto existem notas suficientes para compor o valor.